# Can we execute automated scripts from TFS Web Portal?

Tags: web, azure-pipelines-build-task

Can we execute automated scripts from TFS Web Portal? Option only available for Manual test runs.
Currently VSTS 2012 in use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Try to use a Powershell build task to run the script.